# Highlighting search results when using Laravel Scout

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5

In my application, I am using [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout) with the [TNTSearch Driver](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver) to create a search bar in my site navigation, which is connected to a search method.

The search method searches a bunch of different models and returns what it finds to a view.

**Here is the method:**

```
/**
 * Perform a search given what the user entered into the search box.
 * Uses Laravel Scout to do initial search but because the use of WHERE is limited,
 * we use a filter function instead, on each collection.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function search(Request $request)
{
    // The search string entered
    $search = $request->get('q');

    // Laravel Scout search() method
    $users = User::search($search)->get();
    $articles = Article::search($search)->get();
    $events = Event::search($search)->get();
    $files = FileMetaData::search($search)->get();

    // The date and time as of right now
    $today = Carbon::now();

    /**
     * Below are the filters in place for each model search
     * 1. News articles must be open
     * 2. \Events are split into open and closed
     */
    $articles = $articles->filter(function ($articles) {
        return $articles->published === 'published';
    });

    $upcomingEvents = $events->filter(function ($events) use ($today) {
        return $events->startDate->gt($today);
    });

    $pastEvents = $events->filter(function ($events) use ($today) {
        return $events->startDate->lt($today);
    });

    $userCount = count($users);
    $articleCount = count($articles);
    $eventCount = count($events);
    $upcomingEventCount = count($upcomingEvents);
    $pastEventCount = count($pastEvents);
    $fileCount = count($files);

    return view('pages.search.index', compact('search', 'users', 'articles', 'upcomingEvents', 'pastEvents', 'userCount', 'articleCount', 'upcomingEventCount', 'pastEventCount', 'files', 'fileCount'));
}
```

As you can see, I'm using Scout's `search()` function to search each model and then put some additional constraints on the results, before returning them to my view.

**The view itself**

[image]

I would like the highlighted text at the top to also highlight where appropriate with the search results themselves but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about using the TNT Highlighter class with Laravel.

Trawling through Laracasts forums, I found this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/algolia-highlighting-in-laravel-53?page=1

**Point of interest**

```
<?php

use TeamTNT\TNTSearch\TNTSearch;

$articles = Article::search($searchString)->get();
$tnt = new TNTSearch;

$articles = $articles->map(function($article) use ($searchString, $tnt) {
    $article->title = $tnt->highlight($title, $searchString, 'em'),
});
```

In my case would I need this snippet for each result set?

**An update:**

```
$articles = Article::search($search)->get();

/**
     * Declaire where highlighting should occur for each collection
     */

    // Articles
    $articles = $articles->map(function($article) use ($search, $tnt){
        $article->title = $tnt->highlight($article->title, $search, b, [
            'simple' => false,
            'wholeWord' => false, 
            'tagOptions' => [
                'class' => 'search-term',
                'title' => 'test'
            ]
        ]);

        return $article;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the TNT highlighter, but if you wanted to try your own approach, you could use something like this:

```
/**
* @$str = The string to highlight
* @$search_term = The term we are looking for in $str
**/
function highlightString($str, $search_term) {
    if (empty($search_term))
        return $str;

    $pos = strpos(strtolower($str), strtolower($search_term));

    if ($pos !== false) {
        $replaced = substr($str, 0, $pos);
        $replaced .= '<em>' . substr($str, $pos, strlen($search_term)) . '</em>';
        $replaced .= substr($str, $pos + strlen($search_term));
    } else {
        $replaced = $str;
    }

    return $replaced;
}
```

Just don't forget to style the `<em>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Good solution:

```
public function getTitle($q = null)
{
    if (!$q) {
        return $this->__get('title');
    } else {
        return preg_replace("/($q)/i", '<em>$1</em>', $this->__get('title'));
    }
}
```